# Submit Ajax form after Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a limited understanding of JavaScript, but with some copying and pasting I managed to make a form that gets sent via AJAX.

I'm also running the standard Boostrap 5 input validation. It all worked fine until I found out AJAX fires even without some fields missing.

Then I tried to put the AJAX stuff inside the validation function, but now I need to press "Submit" twice. I understand why, but I don't know how to solve it and would need some help.

This is what I came up with:

```
(function () {
  'use strict'

  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply validation styles to
  var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
    .forEach(function (form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
          event.preventDefault()
          event.stopPropagation()
        } 
    
        form.classList.add('was-validated')
        
        var frm = $('#orderform');
        frm.submit(function (e) {
                var formData = {
                firstName_r: jQuery('#firstName_r').val(),
                lastName_r: jQuery('#lastName_r').val(),
                action:'the_ajax_mail'
            };
            $.ajax({
                type        : 'POST', 
                url         : "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
                data        : formData,
                encode      : true
            }).done(function(data) {
                console.log(data);        
                form.classList.remove('was-validated');
                document.getElementById('submitForm').disabled = true;
            }).fail(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
            e.preventDefault();     
        });


        
      }, false)
    })
})()
```

I know the part with `var frm = $('#orderform');` and `frm.submit(function (e) {` needs to go, but I have no idea how...

Comment: if form isn't valid you should `return` early after canceling it

Comment: Like I said, my understanding is limited. Where do I need to put a `return`? And how do I get rid of the second `submit` which likely causes the double click I need to do before submitting? I have no idea with what to replace `frm.submit(function (e) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
(function() {
  'use strict'

  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply validation styles to
  var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
    .forEach(function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
          event.preventDefault()
          event.stopPropagation()
          return
        }

        form.classList.add('was-validated')

        var formData = {
          firstName_r: jQuery('#firstName_r').val(),
          lastName_r: jQuery('#lastName_r').val(),
          action: 'the_ajax_mail'
        };
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
          data: formData,
          encode: true
        }).done(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          form.classList.remove('was-validated');
          document.getElementById('submitForm').disabled = true;
        }).fail(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        });
        e.preventDefault();


      }, false)
    })
})()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems so easy, but it took me hours today. Now everything works as it should, but in Console I get `502 Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined`: I now just replaced the `e.preventDefault();` with `event.preventDefault();` which seems to do the trick. Thanks again!!!